# Excel Powerquery- is there a real Union?

Tags: excel, powerquery

is there a way to combine two queries in powerquery and remove duplicate records in one step? I am working with over 10M records, doing the steps separately has been taking over 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the M query language. You can create a blank query and add this in the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Query1, Query2}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source)
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

If it's taking too long to do transformations, consider doing one of the following until you have data in the shape you want:

1. Use `Table.Buffer` to store a copy of the table in memory. This will make sure that each step doesn't go back to the server for data, but it will also prevent any query-folding from occurring, so all transformations will be done on your computer.
2. When you connect to the table take only the top 100 or 1000 rows. If you're working against a source like SQL Server that supports query folding then this should greatly speed up your future evaluations.

Once you have the data in the shape you want, you can go back and delete the step.